# How to use async and await on a default function?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, async-await, inputbaraccessoryview

I am having a problem when I am trying to add async and await to a default function.

The function I am trying to add it to is:

```
func inputBar(_ inputBar: InputBarAccessoryView, didPressSendButtonWith text: String)
```

But it looks like when I add async the function will no longer get called when I press the button because it apparently is a different function. How can I fix this?

Comment: Call the function within an asynchronous task, using `await`. Look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/updating_an_app_to_use_swift_concurrency).

Comment: async/await is new api of Swift. You can write another function, mark it as async and put it in a `Task` inside the function you mentioned

Comment: I see! I ended up going with lorem ipsums example but your suggestion sound good as well. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change Apple's function but you can incorporate.

```
var task: Task<Void, Never>? = nil // Put this at class level.

func inputBar(_ inputBar: InputBarAccessoryView, didPressSendButtonWith text: String){

    task?.cancel() // Cancels previous operations
    task = Task{
         //Do something here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I have never heard of this Task before, and it did the trick! Life saver!