# Where should we use "Task {}": in ViewModel or ViewController?

Tags: swift, mvvm, async-await, structured-concurrency

Let's suppose we have some asynchronous code. At some point we must wrap it in a `Task {…}` in order to run it from a synchronous context.
So where is the canonical way to do so? `ViewModel` or `ViewController`?

If we wrap it with `Task {…}` in `ViewModel`, the `ViewModel` functions become effectively synchronous, and calling them from `ViewController` will still require all those completions/delegates/closures/RXs dance to accomplish some UI updates after asynchronous work finishes.

In the other hand, if we mark `ViewModel` functions as `async` and call them from `ViewController` within `Task {…}` body, it seems to solve the problem. So is it a way to go?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use async and await on a default function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76186202/how-to-use-async-and-await-on-a-default-function)

Comment: That strikes me as very different question. This isn’t a question of _how_ to call the `async` function from a synchronous one, but rather _where_ (i.e., the view controller or the view model).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not re-introduce legacy completion patterns (closures, delegates, etc.). That defeats the purpose of Swift concurrency, to gracefully manage asynchronous dependencies. E.g., in WWDC 2021 video [Swift concurrency: Update a sample app](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10194), they show example(s) of how we eliminate completion handlers with Swift concurrency.

So, designate the asynchronous view model methods as `async`. Then, the view controller will use `Task {…}` to enter the asynchronous context of Swift concurrency so that it can `await` the `async` method of the view model and then trigger the UI update when it is done.

But, use of `Task {…}` is not limited to the view controller. The view model may use it, too (e.g., where one needs to save a task in order to possibly cancel it later for some reason).

But you ask:

> if we mark `ViewModel` functions as `async` and call them from `ViewController` within `Task {…}` body, it seems to solve the problem. So is it a way to go?

Precisely. If the method is really doing something asynchronous, then mark it as `async` and the view controller will invoke it from within a `Task {…}`.

---

All of that having been said, in SwiftUI projects, where the view model often communicates updates to the view with `ObservableObject` and `@Published` properties, I would remain within that intuitive and natural pattern. At that point, where you choose to cross into the asynchronous context becomes a little less compelling/critical.

That having been said, from a testability perspective, though, you still want to be able to know when the view model’s asynchronous task is done, so I would probably still make the view model’s methods `async`.